# has_many though relationship does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set up the following association.

## task.rb

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :organziation, through: :user
end
```

## user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :organization
    has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organization
end
```

## organization.rb

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users
end
```

Here is my console output:

```
2.3.0 :001 > t = Task.last
  Task Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" ORDER BY "tasks"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Task id: 3, name: "Register Students", created_at: "2016-08-05 20:00:34", updated_at: "2016-08-05 20:00:34", user_id: 5>
2.3.0 :002 > t.user
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<User id: 5, email: "rich@wintas.com", created_at: "2016-08-05 19:59:56", updated_at: "2016-08-05 20:00:07", organization_id: 1, admin: false>
2.3.0 :003 > t.organization
NoMethodError: undefined method `organization' for #<Task:0x007fbf8bc6d1
```

I want to be able to get directory to a task organization from task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo in association name. Correct it like:

```
has_one :organization, through: :user
```

You had *organziation*, I changed it to *organization*.

Comment: I hate it when that happens! :/

Comment: Thanks for the extra set of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add `has_many :tasks` to Organization model too

Because you see, if the organization is destroyed, all the tasks related to it should be destroyed too if you used `dependent: :destroy` here, also to get all the tasks related to this organization, you might need it